# How can I pass from Java a collection/array of data to procedure call? HANA

Tags: hana

Let's say I have a list of ids:  111, 112, 113 that I fetched executing the following query using Java:

```
SELECT "id" FROM User WHERE (email, name) IN (("", ""), ("", ""));
```

The list length will vary.

From Java I need to pass this list/collection/array of IDs to a stored procedure. How can I do that?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "PROCEDUREEXAMPLE" (IN userIds ??COLLECTION??) LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT SQL SECURITY DEFINER
AS
BEGIN
    //Do the rest
END
```

I wanted to use another procedure to pass the result of first query to the other procedure but as you can see, the first sql is dynamic and the values will vary.

A way to do is to store those ids in a temporary table and the procedure call will access them, but I wanted to know if it possible to pass a collection of data to procedure call.

Feel free to suggest other ways of doing this.
Thanks

Comment: A table can have more than one row. How is a table type not fitting?

Comment: @András sorry, question was confusing because I didn't provide much info. I updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been asked & answered here several times before.
No, it’s not possible to pass a java collection or java array of values into a SAP HANA SQL statement and get the corresponding `IN LIST`.

There is also no mapping of java arrays to SAP HANA SQL arrays.

To deal with that, two main approaches are available:

1. Create the IN-LIST based on the collection elements yourself. This of course can lead to issues with prepared statement reuse, due to the changing number of elements. One way to handle this could be to prepare a statement with a larger number of elements and only bind those for which you got elements in the collection/array.
2. Create a temporary table, fill it with the elements of the collection, one element = one row and use an `INNER JOIN` to filter based on this set of elements.